# Recently, I have installed ROS-Indigo on Trusty 14.04. But most of the packages I found is for hydro. would these package work on Indigo too?

Tags: gazebo, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use iRobot create with Gazebo . But its packages are for hydro: http://answers.ros.org/question/127466/how-to-use-irobot-create-in-gazebo-with-ros-hydro/

I could not find for indigo even for hydro too. when I enter
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-turtlebot
It gives this. and same for indigo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-hydro-turtlebot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191553/recently,-i-have-installed-ros-indigo-on-trusty-14.04.-but-most-of-the-packages-i-found-is-for-hydro.-would-these-package-work-on-indigo-too-?/) by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2014-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install the indigo version using `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-turtlebot`

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on 2014-08-30**:
When I try, I get this answer:
"E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-turtlebot"

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-08-30**:
My apologies, there is no deb for that package yet according to the build farm.  However, you can install it from source from [Github](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot/tree/indigo)

**Comment by [tonyParker](https://answers.ros.org/users/15131/tonyparker/) on 2014-08-30**:
thanks
one last question, I found most of the packages for hydro, should I revert to hydro ?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-08-30**:
Check if you can install the packages you want from source.  They should eventually be released to the debs.